# Перенапрвление сайта с главного на новый и убрать название нвого

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, маршрутизация

Есть сайт, написан на `codegniter`. Работаю над мультиязычностью. Мне надо через файл `.htaccess` сделать так, чтобы при переходе на главную страницу сайта - `example.com`, он перенаправлял меня на сюда - `example.com/en`, (то етсь по дэфолту на английский язык) при условии что название языка в адресе не было видно. То есть - `example.com` подразумевал `example.com/en`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуте так:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /en [L,R=301]
```